# MYSQL retorna OK

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Boa noite amigos,

Alguém consegue me dizer o porque a query abaixo retorna OK?

SELECT count(*) as Dias_uteis
FROM owner.dias_uteis d
WHERE d.data_util
BETWEEN (select ts.criacao from owner.tabela ts where ts.chamado in('1455678','1459783') group by ts.chamado) AND now()

**Preciso contar a quantos dias um chamado foi aberto**
se passo apenas uma condição o contador funciona. Porem quando vou pesquisar mais de um chamado o mysql retorna apenas OK e nada a visualizar.

Comment: Note que seu subselect pode retornar múltiplas datas e não apenas uma.

Comment: Esta sql roda !? Retorna "ok" em um "count" !?

Answer (score 0):

Concordo com o comentário em relação ao retorno de mais de uma data no subselect, e para que seja feita a contagem por chamado, que acredito que seja o objetivo, acho que você deve consultar a tabela de dias úteis no subselect:

```
select 
  ts.chamado,
  (
    SELECT count(*) FROM owner.dias_uteis d 
    WHERE d.data_util BETWEEN ts.criacao AND now()
  ) as Dias_uteis
from owner.tabela ts 
where ts.chamado in ('1455678', '1459783') 
group by ts.chamado
```

Espero que ajude